# 404 Not Found but Route is defined Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

Hello i am  trying to change 2 values from a table in DB,  using Laravel 8, but for some reason, when i press the button to update my data,  i get a 404 not found.  However i have the route defined,  and it appears on the list when i use   php artisan routes:list    I also tried clearing all cache , and it still doesn't work

My controller

```
public function confirmar_pedido_mentoria(Request $request){

        $user = User::findOrFail($request->mentorando_id);

        $user -> area_interesse = $request->area_interesse;
        $user -> pedido_mentoria = 1;
        $user -> update();
  
        return redirect('/admin/pedido_mentoria/{{$user->id}}')->with('msg', 'Pedido realizado com sucesso!');

    }
```

My routes

```
Route::get('/admin/pedido_mentoria/{id}', [UsersController::class, 'pedido_mentoria'])->middleware('auth');
Route::put('/admin/confirmar_pedido/{id}', [UsersController::class, 'confirmar_pedido_mentoria'])->middleware('auth');
```

I put here the get route, because that is the route i intend to user when i redirect after updating the values

My blade view

```
<?php
$inter = $user->interesses->pluck('id')->toArray();
?>

<h1 style="font-family: Eczar">Efectuar Pedido de Nova Mentoria: {{$user->user}}</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <form action="/admin/confirmar_pedido/{{$user->id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="form-group">
                
            <p style="font-family: Eczar">Escolha a Área de Interesse</p>
           
            <div class="form-group">
           
            @foreach($interesses as $interesse)
           
             <input type="radio" name="area_interesse[]" class="area_interesse" value="{{$interesse->id}}" @if (in_array($interesse->id, $inter)) checked="checked" @endif > {{$interesse->area_interesse}} <br/>
            @endforeach
        
           </div>
          
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Escolher">
            </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try to use named route to be on the safest part or rather wrap the link in route() function

Comment: where is the input `mentorando_id` coming from? your redirect in that method is going to be a problem as I doubt something has the 'id' of `'{{$user->id}}'` (as that is a string literal you have there)

Comment: oh god! That was completely stupid of me.  I am not getting the «mentorando_id» from anywhere, so of course, as what MH Malekian said, i need to receive also the ID property.   Thank you!  I was able to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get your id parameter in controller function(confirmar_pedido_mentoria).
Edit your code  :

```
public function confirmar_pedido_mentoria(Request $request,$id){

        ....
    }
```

Comment: But i get the ID i need , from  $request->id . I don't think i need to duplicate the id  ( i tried adding that second ID, however it still doesn't work)

Comment: Damn me  I was kinda blind, that i was trying to use a $request->mentorando_id, from nowhere, so of course i am not getting any ID from the request, and instead i need to get it , by adding to the function as you said.  Thank you!